# When should I use msbuild (.csproj, .sln) and when project.json and dotnet?

Tags: .net, mono, .net-core

.NET/.NET Core/Mono has two build tools: **msbuild** (`.csproj`, `.fsproj`, `.sln` files and `msbuild`/`xbuild` tools) and **dotnet** (`project.json` and `dotnet` tool).

- Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio creates and manages projects in `msbuild` format
- .NET core website [recommends `dotnet` tool on its home page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core)
- Microsoft [deprecates `project.json` in May 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/) however it's still recommended on front page of .NET Core
- .NET core 1.1 still has `dotnet` utility and it still uses `project.json`
- F# website [recommends `msbuild`](http://fsharp.org/guides/mac-linux-cross-platform/#projects-and-build-automation)
- [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) dependency management tool uses `msbuild`

What build system should I use and when?

Comment: is this a greenfield project - or do you have any existing dependencies (in source-form) or infrastructure to contend with?

Comment: @Dai new project (yes, question is mostly about new projects).

Comment: wrt "however it's still recommended on front page of .NET Core", can you provide URL for that?

Comment: @knocte https://www.microsoft.com/net/core, `dotnet new`, `dotnet restore`, `dotnet run`. `dotnet new` will create project.json in current directory in 1.1.0, I tried.

Comment: that is not recommending one over the other, it's simply stating how to use it

Comment: @knocte so they're stating to use `project.json` tooling but at the same time are deprecating it? Does it mean .NET for non-windows and non-visual-studio is made for deception and should not be relied upon?

Comment: it means that the documentation team in M$ sucks, nothing else